# Using 2 try and catch Java

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm creating a program where the use will be asked for 2 phone numbers but if the user writes a string the number will be replaced with 0, I was trying to use these 2 try and catch but only the first one works, do you have any recommendation for mi code?

```
try {
    System.out.println("Insert phone number: ");
    x = scan.nextLong();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error number assigned = 0");
    x = 0;
}
try {
    System.out.println("Insert dial number: ");
    c = scan.nextLong();
    z = c;
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error number assigned = 0");
    z = 0;
}
a.setPhoneNumber(x);
a.setDialPhone(z);
```

Comment: If the first `nextLong()` gets invalid input, you need to move past that token or the second `nextLong` will also throw an exception.

Comment: You should NEVER catch Exception! It is valid to catch RuntimeException or Throwable (in certain cases) but you should NEVER catch Exception, as it hides Exceptions that you should be handling or might not even be aware off.

Comment: @ControlAltDel "NEVER" except of course when you have to, e.g. when invoking `Callable.call` directly.

Comment: @AndyTurner Good point. But then you should catch just to re-throw so it goes to the logs... Then you're going to tell me: "This one time in computer camp..." Exceptions (meant literally, not java.lang.Exception) to exceptions to rules.

Answer (score 0):

plus what  @ControlAltDel said

when exception throw the process will call whatever in the catch closure then if you add finally closure it will be called after that nothing else will be called so anything out side the try will not be called

Runtime should be corrected but not making it happen in the first place like validate the input

so you  can check the scanner using [Scanner.hasNextLong](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLong()) method if it false then set the variable to 0 else set it to whatever there

please notice if it false try to call

```
scan.next();  // but do not save it value to anything as hasLong does not move the reader to the next one it just validate the current one
```

then call for the check the next value same way

so always fine away to not even the exception happen but if it outside of your power then use try catch finally way

and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

You should never use multiple catch blocks for handling the same issue, it's just simply redundant. Next, if you're trying to input some phone numbers then use the correct data type which is `String` not `Long` or `long` - you will never be doing any mathematical operations with the numbers - it's basically an identifier. Normally you'd have a validator for these values which would have methods to validate various formats.

Let's assume you have that validator written and it is capable to `validatePhoneNumber` and to `validateDialNumber` and woulth throw some appropriate exception, let's call it `UserInputException`, if the input didn't satisfy the validator. After that you could do

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String phoneNumber, dialNumber;

    try{
        
        System.out.println("Input phone number:");
        phoneNumber = scanner.next();
        PhoneNumberValidator.validatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        
        System.out.println("Input dial number:");
        dialNumber = scanner.next();
        PhoneNumberValidator.validateDialNumber(dialNumber);
        
    } catch (UserInputException e){
        //handle here
    }
```

The whole use of the catch block there is dubious. This might not a question about how to deal with catch blocks but rather a bad approach all together.